# Codimension of zero set on a complex space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be an irreducible complex space and $f \in \mathcal{O}(X)$. Then $f^{-1}(0)$ is either empty, the whole of $X$, or an analytic set of (pure) codimension 1. From this it follows that for $f_1, \dots, f_p \in \mathcal{O}(X)$, the irreducible components of $f_1^{-1}(0) \cap \dots \cap f_p^{-1}(0)$ have codimension $\leq p$.

I'm curious what happens if we assume that $X$ has pure dimension and drop the assumption of irreducibility in these statements? In the first case we could have that $\dim f^{-1}(0) = \dim X$ while $f^{-1}(0) \neq X$. But could it for example happen that $\text{codim} \, f^{-1}(0) \geq 2$?